# What syntax am i missing here?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

What am i missing within this syntax, i am getting the error expecting ';'. Insert a semi colon at the end? I know it want me to add a semi colon at the end, but where? I don't see the error in my syntax. I am using unityscript within unity3d.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll) {

 if (coll.name.Equals("Cube"))
 { 
    coll.Destroy();
 }
```

right ok i have made the changes you guys suggested, and yes that solved that problem. BUt another error now appears saying 'expected":" found ";"?

```
 function Update () {

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider : coll) {

 if (coll.name.Equals("Cube"))
 { 
    coll.Destroy();
 }

 }

 }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with unity3d, but that is _not_ valid JavaScript. There's no `function` keyword, and JavaScript functions do not declare any return type.

Comment: @epascarello "I am using javascript within unity3d"

Comment: missing } at the end too?

Comment: this is java  not javascript

Comment: This is C# / Unity code, not Javascript. Add "}" in the end. If you already have it but you didn't added to question please add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're really using **JavaScript** on your game. Unity can handle at least 3 languages for its engine: `JavaScript`, `C#` and `Boo`.

Your code seems to be a C# code. If you copied it from a web source, check on it. If it's from your project, check on the Unity IDE.

In case of that event trigger, in **JavaScript** it have to be something near this:

```
function OnTriggerEnter (other : Collider) {
   Destroy(other.gameObject);
}
```

For other languages, see the documentation [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html).

Comment: As a best pratice, the docs are the first place to look when you have a problem in any language/framework!

Answer (score -1):

From what I see - you are missing a closing curved bracket

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll) {
```

This is not closed.